# bootstrap popover not displayed on disabled checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I need to display popover on a disabled checkbox but, for some reason it is not working.

Here is the **fiddler**: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/124/

**HTML**

```
 <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="AccessChkBox"> Click here [this one displays popover]
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="AccessChkBox2"> Click here [this one does not display popover]
    </label>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
function GetAdminNames()
{
    return '<li>Some user name</li>';
}

var accessChkBox = $('#AccessChkBox');
var accessChkBox2 = $('#AccessChkBox2');

var messageToDisplay = "You don't have necessary authorization. Please contact anyone of the following admin to get the authorization.";

messageToDisplay += '<ul>';
messageToDisplay += GetAdminNames();
messageToDisplay += '</ul>';

//now set the popover

accessChkBox.
data('toggle', 'popover').
data('trigger', 'hover').
data('placement', 'right').
data('html', 'true').
prop('title', 'Authorization Status').
data('content', messageToDisplay).popover();  


//this one does not display popover
accessChkBox2.prop('disabled', true);

accessChkBox2.
data('toggle', 'popover').
data('trigger', 'hover').
data('placement', 'right').
data('html', 'true').
prop('title', 'Authorization Status').
data('content', messageToDisplay).popover();
```

In the above code, the 'accessChkBox2' is not displaying popover.

**Expectation:**

accessChkBox2 (this second checkbox which is disabled) should display popover message similar to the first checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated :

Just add class="disabled" - Bootstap will add "not interactable" cursor.
Also, add onclick="return false" - this wont let you check the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="AccessChkBox2" class="disabled" onclick="return false">
```

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/132/

Comment: Sure, I think this solution will work. But, I want to alteast display the checkbox as disabled (appear as disabled using css?) so that users won't keep on clicking it...

Comment: Updated the fiddle link. This should do the job.

Comment: Also, with the updated fiddle, you don't need the onclick="return false".

Comment: Not sure whether I am missing anything.. I don't see the checkbox greyed out with the updated fiddler... also, the second checkbox is still clickable.

Comment: Seems like 'disabled' class has no / less effect on the checkbox. But, I like the solution and I will go with it.